# Error: "Command text was not set for the command object" when running a Stored Procedure from SQL on VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run a stored procedure on VBA using the following VBA code:
Please can someone advise: I get the error at "rs.Open".

```
Sub connection()

   Dim Conn As ADODB.connection
    Dim ADODBCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim constring As String
    Dim location As String  'the server
    Dim password As String


location = "10.103.98.18" 
password = "password"
constring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=" & location & ";Command Timeout=0;Connection Timeout=0;Packet Size=4096; Initial Catalog=ElColibri; User ID=Analyst1; Password=password;"



Set Conn = New ADODB.connection
Conn.connectionString = constring
'On Error GoTo ConnectionError
Conn.Open






'loginstatus = False
'Exit Sub


'errorhandl0
'ConnectionError:
'MsgBox "Not possible to log in. Have you entered the correct password?"

'open recordset
Set ADODBCmd = New ADODB.Command
ADODBCmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
ADODBCmd.CommandTimeout = 1200
ADODBCmd.CommandText = ["ukrmc.dbo.FridayCommentary"]
ADODBCmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
ADODBCmd.Execute
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.ActiveConnection = Conn
rs.Open

Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
Set ADODBCmd = Nothing

'Paste to spreadsheet
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("macrotest").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset
'Set rs = conn.Execute(Query)
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing


End Sub
```

To me the code makes logical sense to me so I am not sure what the error means. Because to me, I have set text for the command object.

Comment: Why is the CommandText string enclosed in square brackets? I have not previously seen that syntax used with a string literal.

Comment: Hi @JohnRC It's my stored procedure. I want to run this stored procedure and paste the output onto a worksheet.

Comment: I meant, you are using the syntax `["ukrmc.dbo.FridayCommentary"]` with square brackets, instead of just using the string literal - what effect to the square brackets have on the literal string?

Comment: @JohnRC I thought this is how I'm meant to write my stored procedure's name. Is this not the case?

Comment: I think you should be able to use the literal string without square brackets. Anyway, I think @FunThomas has provided the right answer to your problem.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to use the SQL syntax, as in `..CommandText = "EXEC ukrmc.dbo.FridayCommentary";  `, with `CommandType = vbCmdText ' 1 - SQL Text ` but not sure whether there are any advantages one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not connecting the recordset to your command. Assuming that your stored procedure issues a `SELECT`, change your code to

```
Set rs = ADODBCmd.Execute
thisWorkbook.Worksheets("macrotest").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs
```

The `Execute`-Method will return a `Recordset` as result, no need to create one by yourself.

Comment: Thanks! this gets me past the execute command but now I have an error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" at "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ...."

Comment: I think you need to provide the recordset object as a parameter.

Comment: I think JohnRC is right, you probably have forgotten to add `rs` as parameter to the `CopyFromRecordset` method.

Comment: Now I have the error "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" but I thought that doing rs.Execute will open the recordset? @JohnRC

Comment: `conn.close` should be the last statement - put it after the `CopyFromRecordset` statement

Answer (score 0):

Or you should add the command object to the open operation

```
rs.Open ADODBCmd
```